# How to arrenge elements of a list down in python

Tags: python

My main goal is to recieve some input and output some text in the following format:

```
"hello how are,
you, I am
good and you"
```

so far I have a code that output a list of strings with each element being a string with three word inside see output of below code

```
guion = "The first law of thermodynamics, also known as the law of conservation of energy, states that energy cannot be created or destroyed, only transformed from one form to another. This means that the total amount of energy in a closed system remains constant.In other words, if you take a system and add energy to it, the energy must go somewhere - it can't just disappear. It may be converted into other forms of energy, such as heat or mechanical work, but the total amount of energy in the system will remain the same.This law is important in understanding many processes in physics and engineering, including the behavior of heat engines, the transfer of heat between objects, and the properties of various materials."
new_guion = guion.split()

def separate(lis):
    full = []
    for i in range(0,len(lis),3):
        newelem = lis[i:i + 3]
        full.append(newelem)
        i+=1
    return full

jo = separate(new_guion)


def joinlis(lis):
    unpacked = []
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        almostunpack = " ".join(lis[i])
        unpacked.append(almostunpack)
        i+=1
    return unpacked

unpc = joinlis(jo)
print(unpc)
```

my problem comes into the final part how can arrange that list to look something like this

```
"hello my name
is sam and
i like python"
```

such that new function outputs a SINGLE string with 3 words per line

Comment: Insert a newline `'\n'` in the result string where you want the line breaks.

Comment: If you make a list of lines, use `"\n".join(lines)`

Comment: @barmar in what part of the code should that be and what about converting the whole list into a single string?

Comment: `i+=1` is useless because the next iteration of the loop resets `i` from the `range()`.

Comment: `print("\n".join(unpc))`

Comment: I get single word lines

Comment: I tried it and I got 3-word lines.

Comment: Proof: https://ideone.com/bQyypm